# overflow hidden content shown in padding area, possible to hide it?

Tags: html, css, overflow

```
<style>
   div{padding:5px;overflow:hidden;height:20px}
</style>
<div class="container">
  something something   something something   something something   something something   something something   something something   something something 
<div>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v21vgzfc/

Is it possible in CSS to make the text hidden also in the padding area without adding another layer?

Comment: question updated. Please see the fiddle.

Comment: Looks like you may have to end using transparent borders (whose thickness is equal to the padding) and remove the padding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, I would use a border instead of padding. Like this:

```
div{
border:solid 5px #00f;
overflow:hidden;
height:20px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think plz give a width to div

```
 <style>
   div{padding:5px;overflow:hidden;height:40px; width:250px; background:#009}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using border, instead of padding.

```
div {
   border: 5px solid blue;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: blue;
   height: 40px
}
```

See how it works in [this Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/v21vgzfc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a nested element inside the parent element and applying `overflow: hidden` to that nested element.

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <!-- Content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```